# ASP.NET: Checkboxes inside a gridview, which is part of modalpopupextender, check status not getting sent to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I have been working on creation of a webpage using ajax modalpopupextender control. I have a gridview with an itemtemplate of checkboxes in it. There are a couple of buttons (Save, Cancel) in the panel containing the gridview. The popup opens correctly and the button events are also called. However, if I check/ uncheck any of the checkboxes and then click on the Save button the checked status always is false.
I've been looking everywhere on the web and tried everything I could. Tried using triggers to no effect. I even created a separate demo web page just to test this out. So far no luck. Just FYI, in case I replace the gridview with say textbox or something, the value is correctly received at the server side. Where could I possibly go wrong? Attached are the snippets:

```html
<asp:Button ID="exButton" runat="server" Text="Select for BA" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ex_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="ex_ModalPopupExtender" TargetControlID="exButton" PopupControlID="Pops" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop" CancelControlID="CancelChange">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Pops" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="modal-dialog">Select</div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; max-height: 400px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridTable" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" runat="server" Style="width: 100%; font-size: small" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Title">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
              <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="Controls col-xs-offset-4">
        <input id="SaveBA_OK" type="button" value="Save" name="SaveBA_OK" runat="server" onserverclick="SaveBA_OK_ServerClick" />
        <input id="CancelChange" type="button" value="Cancel" runat="server" onserverclick="CancelChange_ServerClick" />
      </div>
      <asp:Label ID="LabelPopup" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The backend C# code is as follows:

```html
 protected void SaveBA_OK_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        int m = 0;
        
            
        for (int i = 0; i < gridTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridTable.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                selectedEx.Rows[m][0] = gridTable.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                //selectedEx.Rows[m][1] = "1";
                m = m + 1;
            }

        }
        
        LabelPopup.Text = "success";
    }
```

chk.Checked is always false. And yes, I do check the checkboxes before clicking on the Save button. Please help. :-/

Comment: where are you binding gridview.?

Comment: in the pageload event

Comment: are you binding your gridview inside  `if (!IsPostBack)` .?

Comment: I hadn't. Wow! This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: always check for this when you face this kind of situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the rows using the `foreach` loop

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gridTable.Rows)
 {
    CheckBox chk = row.Cells[1].Controls[1] as CheckBox;
    if ((chk != null) && chk.Checked)
    {
            // Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

This probably be the same thing with different approach,but you have set `AutoPostBack` to false so why the `OnCheckedChanged`

Check your `PageLoad` event

I see you have `UpdatePanel` controls. Try setting up a Trigger in the UpdatePanel that contains the GridView to link to the Click of the `UpdatePanel` with the save button

Comment: That is essentially the same thing as what I've done. chk.Checked is false anyway so it never enters the if-block. I've tried your snippet too though.

Comment: @One Check out your page load event. Are you binding on every postback

Comment: @One Glad that it helped :)